# How to interpret the Expected Value?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say the cost of a ticket is 1 dollar.
The odds of winning is 1 out of 228 million.
The prize is 300 million dollars.
So, the expected value is 0.32 dollars.

I'm not sure how to interpret this "expected value." What does it mean? That I can expect to make 0.32 dollars each time I buy a ticket? wut? lol

Comment: How did you get $\$0.32$?

Comment: In this kind of situations (individual cases) it doesn't mean anything. In other contexts, especially when you are considering a large ensemble (population), like gas particles, you can use the expected value

Comment: Over the course of trying many tickets you will profit about 0.32 dollars each. As the number of tickets goes to infinity this becomes exact. Note that to get this level of accuracy you would need to try so many tickets that you win many different times.

Comment: @Ian, I wouldn't recommend buying an infinite number of lottery tickets

Comment: I assume that you calculated $228/300\approx 1.32$. The expected value is actually $1.32$ dollars in this case. This kind of lottery is not very common, as the expected win per ticket is larger than the price of the ticket.

Comment: @MattiP., How did you get $228/300$ to be $>1$?

Comment: i calculated the expected value as $\frac{(\$300\ million\ -\ \$1)(1)\ +\ (-\$1)(228\ million\ -\ 1)}{228\ million}$

Comment: so, basically, if i buy 228 million tickets, I'll likely make \$0.32 for every ticket!?

Comment: oops, I meant $300/228 \approx 1.32$.

Comment: @Zac It would take a lot more than 228 million tickets before you would expect to see a good long run average, because of the variability in the number of tickets it takes to win. You're actually looking at more like 20 billion tickets before you see a clean average (and continuing to study probability will tell you how I calculated that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the probability of winning is $p=\frac{1}{228} \cdot 10^{-6}$ and the prize is $x= \$ 300 \cdot 10^6$ then your expected value will be just $$x \cdot p=\frac{\$ 300}{228}=\frac{\$ 25}{19} \approx \$ 1.316$$ Which means if you buy $228$ million tickets, you might get $\$ 1.316$ for every ticket, yes. If you win. But this is just one lottery, so you can only win one single time. There's a chance you will not win and won't get any revenue for your money.

But to make winning more likely, you'd have to participate in hundreds of such lotteries, and buy $228$ million tickets each time. Then you will really get approximately this expected value for each dollar you've spent.

Answer (score 0):

The interpretation is meaningful from the point of view of the lottery company.
They do have a large number of experiments and $1$ minus the expected value times the actual number of participants is their profit with high accracy.

Answer (score 0):

If there are $228$ million tickets costing $\$1$ each and exactly one of them will win $\$300$ million then the ticket purchasers will collectively gain a net $\$72$ million

That is an average net gain of almost $\$0.32$ per ticket